# Redis Transaction

Tags: c#, redis

Is there any flag on transaction object that indicates that transaction has started/inprocess/completed?

`var transaction = Idatabase.CreateTransaction()` (I am using most recent c# client)

I would like to know if there is anything on transaction object I can use that will tell me if the transaction has started apart from object not being null.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you can, but to be honest, if you get to a point using Redis where you have to monitor if a command is running, it kind of means something is wrong. Using redis you expect that transaction to run immediately.

Comment: @bitoiu, I am trying to add a wrapper over redis client. Hard time I have is to wrap the transaction object. Only way I can do is to have one transaction object in my custom class and see if transaction has been created and if yes then I can call methods on that transaction object instead of using Idatabase in my wrapped method.  E.g string CustomStringGet(string key) {if(_transaction is null) Idatabase.StringGet(key) else _trasaction.StringGet(key)} _transaction is a Itransaction object in my custom class.

Comment: continued:  Now I want to know if there is any property that I can use on _transaction which tells if transaction has initiated

Comment: how do you define transaction. is a REDIS GET a transaction? you mean a connection instead of a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

If you get a response, the transaction is started. There are no commands to manage or check the state of a transaction, it's a simple lean API provided by Redis and wrapped in your C# client.

https://redis.io/topics/transactions#usage

> A Redis transaction is entered using the MULTI command. The command always replies with OK.